# Calculating phi11 (or phi22) from an MA(1) process

Tags: time-series, arima, arma

I've come across a question where I have an MA(1) process like so:

$X_t = b_t - 0.4 b_{t-1}$ (where $b_t$ is a white noise process and $t$ is the time index)

The question asks me to find $\phi_{11}$ ([Phi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi)) and $\phi_{22}$

From what my notes say:

- $\phi$ is from the AR(1) process.
- There exists a technique to convert an MA(1) process into an infinite AR process

However, I cannot find any information or techniques for converting an MA(1) process into an AR(1) process or even for using the $\theta$ ([Theta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta)) value as a means for converting into the $\phi$ value.

Is there something I am missing in this time series problem?

For some extra info:

- I have calculated the mean of the MA(1) process
- I also have the variance
- I also have autocorrelations for $k=0$, $k=1$

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems I have come across something called the PACF of the MA(1) process.

I think I may have confused the Phi in the AR(1) process with this other Phi. I'm not even sure they are related.

The formulae are:

Phi11 = Rho1 = -Theta1 / 1 + Theta1^2

Phi22 = - (Rho1^2 / 1 - Rho1^2)

Comment: $\phi_i$'s and $\phi_{ii}$'s are related.